¿Cuál es la mejor forma de crear un programa multilenguaje en Tkinter?
llevo varios días queriendo agregar una opción en un combobox en tkinter que pueda cambiar de español a ingles todas las cadenas de texto del programa, pero no he podido, lograrlo, por el momento logro traducir todo lo que hay en el frame actual, pero digamos que hay mas labels y cosas asi de texto en otro frames que no son visibles actualmente, entonces me arroja error de que estoy intentando traducir algo que no esta o sea ha destruido y pues tiene razon ya que actualmente hay labels y otros widgets en diferentes frames, el código es extenso y lo tengo en diferentes módulos para evitar la importación circular  ya que digamos que en un archivo importo todos los widgets para traducirlos y así.
si alguien ha hecho algo por el estilo o tenga idea de que como hacerlo le agradecería mucho su ayuda.

No se como estás implementando la localización, pero gettext junto a GNU-xgettext / pygettext o babel suele ser lo más "universal".

Realmente la manera más sencilla que se me ocurre para esto es que tengas un fichero con extensión ".json", y en éste, indiques el idioma en el que se representará tu interfaz gráfica.
# En un fichero denominado por ejemplo lenguaje.json:
{"idioma":"espanol"}

A continuación, TODO (absolutamente todo) el texto de tu interfaz gráfica se debería encontrar declarado en constantes o en variables según corresponda al inicio de cada uno de tus módulos relacionados a la interfaz gráfica, y que todo este texto se encuentre condicionado por un "if", en el que compruebes el valor del archivo Json, de forma que en el archivo json tengas algo más o menos así:
if funcionObtenerLenguajeDesdeJson() == "espanol":
    TXT_TITULO = "Texto del título"
    BTN = "Texto botón"
elif funcionObtenerLenguajeDesdeJson() == "ingles":
    TXT_TITULO = "Title text"
    BTN = "Button text"

De esta forma, como tienes todo declarado con variables/contantes, no hace falta que cambies nada del código, ya que con que simplemente cambie el valor de las variables tendrás la traducción hecha.
Esto te permitiría por ejemplo implementar todos los idiomas que quieras de forma sencilla. En Python tienes una librería que viene de serie denominada "json", con la que puedes leer y escribir datos de un fichero Json para crear tus propias funciones para aplicar esto que te he comentado.

Personalmente, esos if no me gustan nada. Ya que vas a tener un fichero json simplemente llámalos es.json y en.json y cuando cambias el idioma lo único que haces es volver a cargar el fichero json usando el idioma para montar el nombre dinámicamente language + ".json". A grandes rasgos :) Así si quieres añadir otro idioma no hay que tocar código, es solo crear el fichero y ya está

Es otra alternativa. Hay cientos de formas, tú simplemente aplica la que más te agrade/convenga :)
